# Pig Job hangs when using Elephant Bird jsonLoader

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, elephantbird

This is in continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139970/pig-create-json-file-with-actual-key-name-and-values)

My new pig script is:

```
register /usr/hdp/current/pig-client/lib/piggybank.jar
register /opt/elephantbird-jars/elephant-bird-core-4.5.jar
register /opt/elephantbird-jars/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.5.jar
register /opt/elephantbird-jars/elephant-bird-pig-4.5.jar
register /opt/elephantbird-jars/json-simple-1.1.1.jar

data_input = LOAD 'local/path/for/hdfs/files' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader() AS (json:map[]);

x = FOREACH data_input GENERATE json#'actor__id' AS actor_id,    json#'actor__image__url' AS actor_image_url, json#'actor__displayName' AS actor_displayname, json#'actor__verification__adHocVerified' AS actor_verification, json#'actor__url' AS actor_url;

STORE x INTO '/tmp/user_posts' USING JsonStorage();
```

This code works in local mode: `pig -x local user_posts.pig`

But it fails in mapreduce mode: `pig -x mapreduce user_posts.pig`

I moved the jars to all the data nodes in the exact same location. I am not sure where else to check. Can someone please give some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some issue with my machine and not any problem with pig. I rebooted the machine and everything went well.

Comment: If you agree that this question is unlikely to help future visitors, please delete it to keep the site clean.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `;` everywhere

```
REGISTER '/me/home/elephant-bird-core-4.12.jar';
REGISTER '/me/home/elephant-bird-pig-4.12.jar';
REGISTER '/me/home/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.12.jar';
```